# How to force login to a non-default shell on the remote machine?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sh

You may find the similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/162018/force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-shell). But I think my case is different.

I have a program running in remote machine on `ash` shell which will not allow me to access the `shell` itself i.e, it runs an instance whenever I open a `ssh` session and I cannot execute normal commands like `cd` `mkdir` etc. It could be listed in the `/etc/profile` and so it is executing always when I open a session.

I am aware that there are some other `shells` like `sh`.

So I want here to log in to `sh` and not `ash` so that I can suppress that `process` blocking me.

If I execute

```
  ssh root@192.168.x.x /bin/sh "some command"
```

I think it actually enters into the default shell `ash` and on it, it executes `bin/sh "some command"` and quits.

Am I correct here?

How do I do this work??

Comment: As far as I know the shell is set by login so you have to modify the last entry of /etc/passwd. However as pointed out by  @JesseSielaff there are some utility you can use. See this (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-bash-as-your-default-shell/).

Comment: @JesseSielaff Are you asking me login like this `ssh root@x.x.x.x chsh`? I beleive that the default shell will execute it. I mean it is similar to executing 
`root@ash#chsh`

Comment: Why do you think your case is different than the question that you linked to?

Comment: You can try `ssh root@192.168.x.x exec /bin/sh "some command"`, which immediately *replaces* your login shell instance with an instance of `/bin/sh`, but you can't prevent the login shell from starting in the first place; `sshd` does that before it looks at the command you send via `ssh`.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that, no, there is likely no way to make the remote ssh server launch a command using a different shell than the remote account's login shell, or without using a shell at all.

But let's start with the client.  When you run:

```
ssh root@192.168.x.x /bin/sh "some command"
```

The ssh process receives three command-line arguments:

1. `root@192.168.x.x`
2. `/bin/sh`
3. `some command`

Notably, the double quotes will be stripped from the third argument. The ssh protocol specifies the command to be executed as a single string, *not* a list of individual command-line arguments. So the ssh client is going to concatenate the second and third argument into a single string, `/bin/sh some command`, and send that to the remote server for execution. The fact that "some command" was supposed to be a single argument will be lost. If you want to preserve quotes in the remote command, you would run something like this:

```
ssh root@192.168.x.x '/bin/sh "some command"'
```

Turning to the server, the most widely used SSH server is [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/), so that's what I'll talk about. The OpenSSH server, a program called `sshd`, *always* uses the remote user's login shell to run session commands. Having said that, there are a few scenarios.

1. If the remote client is subject to a forced command--set in the user's authorized_keys file or the server's sshd configuration--then the server will use the forced command as the command to run.
2. If the remote client requested a subsystem like sftp, then the server will find the correct `Subsystem` line in its configuration file, and get the command to be executed from that. [There is a subsystem named "internal-sftp" which gets special treatment, but it's not relevant here.]
3. The remote client can specify a command string to run, as described above.
4. The remote client can request a session without specifying a particular command to run.

To actually start the session, the OpenSSH server looks up the user's login shell. If there's no command to run, the server simply runs the shell with no arguments. For the other three cases, it runs the equivalent of:

```
$SHELL -c 'the command'
```

where $SHELL is the user's shell, and `the command` is the command string.

So, finally: No matter how you specify the command to run, the server is going to run it through the equivalent of `$SHELL -c 'command'`. For this to do what you want, the user's login shell has to accept a `-c` parameter and a command to run on its command line. All of the common shells--Bourne shell, bash, csh, zsh, etc.--will accept this syntax and parse the specified command using their own command syntax.

If your access to the server is subject to a forced command, then you are out of luck. The server is going to run the forced command instead of the command you requested.

If your account on the server is set to use a shell which doesn't act like a traditional shell, then you are out of luck. The server is going to launch your login shell and that program is going to do whatever it does.

The only real caveat here is that, hypothetically, the server which you're connecting to may not use OpenSSH. There are [other SSH servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers) out there--generally commercial ones--and hypothetically, one of them might offer different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

ssh user@host '/bin/bash' < shell.txt